# Translating the Relational Algebra output

Tags: relational-algebra

I have the following relation `Jobs(name, company, salary)`.

```
P1(salary) = πsalary(σcompany='pwc'(Jobs))
P2(salary) = πsalary(ρT1(s)(P1) thetaJoin(s>salary) P1)
P3(salary) = P1 − P2
```

I know that `P1` just selects the salary of all people works in `pwc`.

I am having a hard time figuring out what `P2` indicates.

I know that `ρT1(s)(P1)` renames `P1` into `T1` and the `salary` attribute to `s`. But then I am confused with the `thetaJoin(s>salary)` part because I thought `s` and `salary` would be the same.

`P3` would just be the difference between `P1` and `P2`

The final relation

```
Final(name) = πname(Jobs thetaJoin(salary>s) ρT2(s)(P3))
```

will depend on what `P2` means.

Please help me doing this translation.

Answer (score 3):

```
P2(salary) = πsalary(ρT1(s)(P1) thetaJoin(s>salary) P1)
```

From the Wikipedia entry for [Relational Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#%CE%B8-join_and_equijoin):

> The result of the θ-join is defined only if the headers of S and R are disjoint, that is, do not contain a common attribute.
>
> The simulation of this operation in the fundamental operations is therefore as follows:
>
> R ⋈θ S = σθ(R × S)

To ensure the headers are **disjoint**, salary must be renamed (as 's' here). To ensure the relations are uniquely named for this **self-join**, P1 must also be renamed (as 'T1' here).

In rough SQL terms:

```
DECLARE @P1 table (salary integer NOT NULL);
INSERT @P1 (salary) VALUES (1), (2), (3);

WITH T1 (s) AS (SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM @P1)
SELECT DISTINCT
    P1.salary
FROM @P1 AS P1 
JOIN T1
    ON T1.s > P1.salary;

-- or, closer to the fundamental operations:

WITH T1 (s) AS (SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM @P1)
SELECT DISTINCT
    P1.salary
FROM @P1 AS P1
CROSS JOIN T1
WHERE T1.s > P1.salary;
```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=54c0783c7dbc2ad63794455be441f5a0)

```
| salary |
| ------ |
|      1 |
|      2 |
```

P2 therefore contains all the salary values that are smaller than some other salary value.

P1 minus P2 therefore contains the top salary at PWC.

See also [Finding a Maximum Value with Relational Algebra](https://happylinguist.com/2013/01/24/finding-a-maximum-value-with-relational-algebra/)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following as something to verify, because I am not an expert in relational algebra.

`s` and `salary` seem to me definitely not the same, because they belong to different relation. If you consider them the same, you probably consider `P1` and `P2` the same - again, it is not the case. Each result of a relational operation should be considered as a standalone relation.

In my understanding, `P2` contains all the rows from `P1` whose salary is not the lowest one (if it is, `s>salary` is false). As you correctly state, `P3` is the difference, so it contains the row(s) with the lowest salary.